# While loop ends despite conditions not being met

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code that keeps on asking for input until the sum of two consecutive numbers is a three-digit number, positive and even. For example (the words in bold are the input)

Input? **23** Input? **-21** Input? **120** Input? **-2**

23 + −21 = 2 is not 3-digit; −21 + 120 = 99 is not 3-digit and not even. Then, 120 + −2 = 118 is 3-digit, positive, and even. So, program stops.

However, I wrote a code like this, and after I typed the first two numbers the code ended, despite not being three-digit, positive nor even. What did I do wrong?

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Input? ";
    int a, b, c, sum;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Input? ";
    cin >> b;
    sum = a+b;
    while (sum>=0) {
        cout << "Input? ";
        cin >> c;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    while (sum%2==1) {
        cout << "Input? ";
        cin >> c;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    while (sum<100 && sum>999) {
        cout << "Input? ";
        cin >> c;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Nvm, I forgot to change sum. However, there is still an issue. The code never ends, as it keeps on asking me for input. My new code:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a, b, c, sum;
    cout << "Input? ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Input? ";
    cin >> b;
    sum = a+b;
    while (sum>=0) {
        cout << "Input? ";
        cin >> c;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        sum = a+b;
    }
    while (sum%2==1) {
        cout << "Input? ";
        cin >> c;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        sum = a+b;
    }
    while (sum<100) {
        cout << "Input? ";
        cin >> c;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        sum = a+b;
    }
    while (sum<999) {
        cout << "Input? ";
        cin >> c;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        sum = a+b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you try to debug you will find the reason in 2 seconds! the code is clearly wrong! :)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I have changed that part of the code, yet it still doesn't work. It keeps on asking me for input.

Comment: You should really learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It will help you immensely not only now, but in every single future contact with programming.

Comment: Does your input ensure that every of your condition is not met in correct order? I.E. you make sure that `sum` is first negative, then odd, then greater than `100` and then greater than `999`?

Comment: Hmmn I just noticed that as well, but what order would be correct?

Comment: Do not ignore the advice to learn how to debug. Use a debugger or have the program print the values of your variables and the position within the program on the console (the debugger is the better choice). I think you should really fix this by yourself, because the next time one of your programs has a bug, you'd have to ask other people again if you are not able to do this on your own.

Comment: how do you debug on Xcode?

Comment: ah nvm, I found out myself

Comment: The logic would be easier to code if you combined all of those loops into one. Still, debugging the current form might lend insight into *why* you should combine the loops.

Comment: @AMU, if the answer was useful, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

I really believe in the pedagogical and educational purpose of stackoverflow: it is one of the best teachers ever!

In order to let you understand that you can use `printf` (or `cout` like in your case) as a simpler debug method, here I post a simple version of the code enriched with some comments. The line

```
cout << "the input is " << a << endl; //you can use this line everywhere as primitive debug method
```

can be inserted in every point of your code to print the critical information. I really want to push you to explore the world of debug (for example using [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). There are a hundred different ways of doing that.

However, a version of the code that does the job is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int previous_number, current_number;
    // run this loop forever until two consecutive input satisfy the conditions
    cout << "Input? ";
    cin >> previous_number;
    //cout << "the input is " << a << endl; //you can use this line everywhere as primitive debug method

    while(1){ //run this loop forever until the conditions are satisfied
        cout << "Input? ";
        cin >> current_number;
        if( (previous_number + current_number) < 0 ){
            cout << "the sum of the numbers is negative:'" << (previous_number + current_number) <<"'. Insert another input " << endl;
            previous_number=current_number;
        } else if ( (previous_number + current_number) < 100 || (previous_number + current_number) > 999 ){
            cout << "the sum of the numbers is not a three-digit number:'" << (previous_number + current_number) <<"'. Insert another input " << endl;
            previous_number=current_number;
        } else if ( (previous_number + current_number) % 2 == 1 ){
            cout << "the sum of the numbers is odd:'" << (previous_number + current_number) <<"'. Insert another input " << endl;
            previous_number=current_number;
        } else {
            cout << "the sum of the numbers is odd, positive and three-digit:'" << (previous_number + current_number) <<"'. " << endl;
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
    cout << "------The END------" << endl;
}
```

When using your inputs, the output is:

```
Input? 23
Input? -21
the sum of the numbers is not a three-digit number:'2'. Insert another input 
Input? 120
the sum of the numbers is not a three-digit number:'99'. Insert another input 
Input? -2
the sum of the numbers is odd, positive and three-digit:'118'.
```

> **Please note** that there are many `cout` in the code. The reason is to find possible code-mistakes. This is one of the simpler way of
>   **debugging** your code.